# provider hosted app - access a list in mysite

Tags: office-365, provider-hosted-app

I am creating a provider hosted app for O365 and have given `read` permission on `tenant`. Is there any way, I can access a list present in `mysite` of **any** user (not just the current user)?

If for example, I create a context by hardcoding the mysite url, then it gives me `Forbidden` error.

Comment: are you able to access the given list in my site of the current user?

Comment: yes I was able to.

Comment: provider hosted or sharepoint hosted app? and how did you read the users mysite list?